# How can I get specific data from JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

How can I get specific data from **JSON**?

**JSON:**

```
[
    { "TotalPageCount":  66 },
    { "TotalTitleCount": 199 },
    { "Title":           "cola" },
    { "Title":           "elvis tom" },
    { "Title":           "dvd" }
]
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
<script>
    function updateTitlesArea() {
        $.getJSON(
        "/lates/json/",
        null,
        function(data) {
            $("#titlesDiv").html("");
            $("#pagesDiv").html("");
            var x;
            if (data.length > 0) {
                for (x in data) {
                    $("#titlesDiv").html($("#titlesDiv").html() +
                        "<li><a href=\"/" + data[x].Title.replace(/ /g, '-') + "\">" + data[x].Title + "</a>" +
                        "</li>"
                );
                }
            } else {
                $("#titlesDiv").html("<li>no entry</li>");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I'm trying to get `{"TotalPageCount":66}` AND `{"TotalTitleCount":199}`
from Javascript. Please provide me a method to get them?

Thanks a lot.

## Update

Something going wrong, I tried all solutions but not worked fine.
**I have control on json format:**

**Current Json Builder:**

> ```
>                 if (title.Any())
>                 {
>                     foreach (var x in title)
>                     {
>                         result.AddLast(new { Title = x.Title });
>                     }
>                 }
>                 result.AddLast(new { TotalPageCount = totalPageCount });
>                 result.AddLast(new { TotalTitleCount = totalTitleCount });
>
>                 return Json(result.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
> ```

I made a small change in json format, took totalpage and title count to end of json.

**Current:**

> [{"Title":"kola"},{"Title":"yilmaz
> ozdil"},{"Title":"dvd"},{"Title":"truly madly
> deeply"},{"Title":"deportivo de la coruna"},{"Title":"sizi seven
> kisiyle sevdiginiz kisinin farkli olmasi"},{"Title":"kadinlarin bavul
> gibi canta tasimalari"},{"Title":"hosbuldum"},{"Title":"sark
> cibani"},{"Title":"mevsimler gecerken"},{"Title":"bir kerede kolon
> gibi sicmak"},{"Title":"gelismek"},{"Title":"faz ve alasim
> bilimi"},{"Title":"memetq"},{"Title":"ogrencilerin sinav kagidina
> dustugu ilginc notlar"},{"Title":"cami duvarina
> isemek"},{"Title":"kufurden sonra tovbe etmek"},{"Title":"gida tarim
> ve hayvancilik bakanligi"},{"Title":"cevre orman ve sehircilik
> bakanligi"},{"Title":"google da nikah masasi
> calmak"},{"TotalPageCount":9},{"TotalTitleCount":199}]

With my code and given examples I still couldn't get the TotalPageCount and TotalTitleCount.

For the record: Maybe next time I can add more attributes next to **Title**.
So I would like to keep that json format.

Thanks for advance

Comment: data[0].TotalPageCount

Comment: Don't use `for-in` on Arrays, and don't do `$("#titlesDiv").html($("#titlesDiv").html() +` since it's unnecessarily destructive and inefficient. I can't believe the answerers aren't correcting these patterns.

Comment: And if you control the JSON structure, a more sensible approach may be `{"TotalPageCount":  66,"TotalTitleCount": 199, "Titles": ["cola","elvis tom","dvd"]}`

Answer (score 1):

When you do `x in data` you get every key of objects. So you have to do a simple check if it's `TotalPageCount` or `TotalTitleCount`. Like this;

```
<script>
    function updateTitlesArea() {
        $.getJSON(
            "/lates/json/",
            null,
            function(data) {
                var x, totalPageCount, totalTitleCount;
                $("#titlesDiv").html("");
                $("#pagesDiv").html("");
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    for (x in data) {
                        if('TotalPageCount' == x) {
                            totalPageCount = data[x];
                            continue;
                        }
                        if('TotalTitleCount' == x) {
                            totalTitleCount = data[x];
                            continue;
                        }
                        $("#titlesDiv").html($("#titlesDiv").html() +
                            "<li><a href=\"/" + data[x].Title.replace(/ /g, '-') + "\">" + data[x].Title + "</a>" +
                            "</li>"
                        );
                    }
                    // You can do here whatever you want with 'totalPageCount' and 'totalTitleCount'
                } else {
                    $("#titlesDiv").html("<li>no entry</li>");
                }
            });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an array, so

```
if (data.length > 0) {
    var obj = data[0];   // array, not object
     for (key in obj) { 
          $("#titlesDiv").html(
              $("#titlesDiv").html() +
                 "<li><a href=\"/" + obj[key].Title.replace(/ /g, '-') + "\">" + 
                     obj[key].Title + "</a>" +
                 "</li>"
          );
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery right? You can try something like this:

```
var prom = $.getJSON('/lates/json/'),
    ar;
prom.then(function (data) { ar = data; });
```

After that, you will have the response array in **ar**. You will be able to access to your required values in this fashion:

```
ar[0].TotalPageCount
ar[1].TotalTitleCount
```

I hope this will help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

With your current JSON format, it'd be something like this. It'd be better if you could change the JSON format, though.

```
<script>
    function updateTitlesArea() {
        $.getJSON(
            "/lates/json/",
            null,
            function(data) {
                $("#titlesDiv").html('<ul></ul>'); // <li> goes inside <ul> or <ol>
                $("#pagesDiv").empty();

                var has_titles = false;

                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if("Title" in data[i]) {
                        $("#titlesDiv ul").append(
                            '<li><a href="/' + data[i].Title.replace(/ /g, '-') + '">' + data[i].Title + "</a>" +
                            "</li>"
                        );
                        has_titles = true;
                    }
                }
                if( !has_titles ) {
                    $("#titlesDiv ul").html("<li>no entry</li>");
                }
            }
        );
    }
</script>
```